# When the button is pressed the app crashes

Tags: java, android, crash

I use android studio on my emulator applications work perfectly.

But when I started on real device (Samsung Galaxy S4 and Galaxy S6) application is launched but when I click the button it stops working.

Here is my code:

```
ImageView left, middle, right;
    List<Integer> cards;
    Button newGame;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cards = new ArrayList<>();
        cards.add(1); // 5 of diamonds
        cards.add(2); // 7 of diamonds
        cards.add(3); // 1  of spades

        Collections.shuffle(cards);

        newGame = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNewGame);
        left = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivCardLeft);
        middle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivCardMiddle);
        right = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivCardRight);

        newGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Collections.shuffle(cards);
                left.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
                middle.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
                right.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardback);
                Animation animLeft =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.left);
                Animation animMiddle =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.middle);
                Animation animRight =  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.right);
                left.startAnimation(animLeft);
                middle.startAnimation(animMiddle);
                right.startAnimation(animRight);

            }
        });

        left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cards.get(2) == 1) {
                    left.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
                } else if (cards.get(2) == 2) {
                    left.setImageResource(R.drawable.seven);
                } else if (cards.get(2) == 3) {
                    left.setImageResource(R.drawable.ace);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Guessed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                if (cards.get(1) == 1) {
                    middle.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
                } else if (cards.get(1) == 2) {
                    middle.setImageResource(R.drawable.seven);
                } else if (cards.get(1) == 3) {
                    middle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ace);

                }
                if (cards.get(0) == 1) {
                    right.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
                } else if (cards.get(0) == 2) {
                    right.setImageResource(R.drawable.seven);
                } else if (cards.get(0) == 3) {
                    right.setImageResource(R.drawable.ace);

                }
            }
        });
        middle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cards.get(2) == 1) {
                    left.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
                } else if (cards.get(2) == 2) {
                    left.setImageResource(R.drawable.seven);
                } else if (cards.get(2) == 3) {
                    left.setImageResource(R.drawable.ace);


                }
                if (cards.get(1) == 1) {
                    middle.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
                } else if (cards.get(1) == 2) {
                    middle.setImageResource(R.drawable.seven);
                } else if (cards.get(1) == 3) {
                    middle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ace);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Guessed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                if (cards.get(0) == 1) {
                    right.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
                } else if (cards.get(0) == 2) {
                    right.setImageResource(R.drawable.seven);
                } else if (cards.get(0) == 3) {
                    right.setImageResource(R.drawable.ace);

                }
            }
        });
        right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (cards.get(2) == 1) {
                    left.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
                } else if (cards.get(2) == 2) {
                    left.setImageResource(R.drawable.seven);
                } else if (cards.get(2) == 3) {
                    left.setImageResource(R.drawable.ace);


                }
                if (cards.get(1) == 1) {
                    middle.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
                } else if (cards.get(1) == 2) {
                    middle.setImageResource(R.drawable.seven);
                } else if (cards.get(1) == 3) {
                    middle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ace);

                }
                if (cards.get(0) == 1) {
                    right.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
                } else if (cards.get(0) == 2) {
                    right.setImageResource(R.drawable.seven);
                } else if (cards.get(0) == 3) {
                    right.setImageResource(R.drawable.ace);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Guessed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dusan.cupd">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.dusan.cupd.MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cardback"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivCardLeft" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cardback"
            android:id="@+id/ivCardMiddle" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cardback"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:id="@+id/ivCardRight" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnNewGame"
        android:text="New Game"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Button `new game` work, but game crashes when i click on any of Cards.(left,middle,right)

My Logcat :

```
11-27 13:42:46.754 30166-30166/com.example.dusan.cupd E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.dusan.cupd, PID: 30166
                                                                        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
                                                                            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
                                                                            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3056)
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1613)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:128)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:45)
                                                                            at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:346)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:185)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:69)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
                                                                            at com.example.dusan.cupd.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:103)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: put your logcat error

Comment: you can get logcat on real devices too

Comment: I connected galaxy S4 i have some problems with S6

Comment: Add android:largeHeap="true" in your android Manifest file with in the application tag

Comment: that work but 1 card is now invisible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you should edit your question not adding an answer, second put this in application tag in your manifest file

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: Ok it works thank you.but can you explane to me what that do?And now my ace of spade is invisible

Comment: where is "ace of spade"? i didn't saw that on your xml file

Comment: i added comment in my main activity cards.add(3); // 1  of spades